# Please show me why highlight.js doesn't work

Tags: html, highlight

I try to use the highlight.js but it didn't work

i work like they say in the website but i don't know what's wrong

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.6/highlight.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.6/styles/default.min.css">
    <script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
    <pre>
        <code class="javascript">
                        var D = new Date();
        </code>
    </pre>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I expect the code in the pre tag to display properly but it will only display as a regular text. Please help me !
Or someone can use another way to help me show the code the way stackoverflow displays.

Comment: its  working fine,check my edit.It seems you have some other issue

Comment: I have followed the instructions on the internet many times but it still does not work. Does Google Chrome support display?

Comment: post the console error here

Comment: @Drac have you checked console in google chrome (opens with key f12) for any errors out there, If any please post here.

Comment: Console: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND              file://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.6/styles/default.min.css

Comment: Oh I solved the problem, when copying the link for style, it doesn't have 'https: //'. I am a newbie so I have a silly mistake. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.6/styles/default.min.css">
```

check the difference here, you are missing https: in the cdn url. I have changed it and it works fine.

Comment: @Drac nice to hear that...please vote my answer as accepted one!

Comment: In fairness, the [docs](https://highlightjs.org/usage/) show the paths in the CDN URLs without `https:` too, and when I use them in that format the files are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I am very tired and trying this from many hours and it won't work, then I added https: before css and js cdn and it worked like a charm.
monokai working cds are given below

css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.10/styles/monokai.min.css">
```

js

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.10/highlight.min.js"></script>
```

highlight js

```
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```